# Exception occurred creating type 'Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditControls.EditBox

Tags: .net, janus

I have a windows application and in that i have used Janus control. when building the code using Licence file its throwing a error-
Exception-

> Properties\licenses.licx(1, 0): error LC0004: Exception occurred creating type 'Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditControls.EditBox, Janus.Windows.GridEX.v3, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21d5517571b185bf' System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

Do anyone has any idea why i am getting this error.
When i am building locally its not throwing any error when building using Teamcity then getting the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Is Teamcity installed on another machine?
Janus is looking for registry settings under path 'HKLM\Software\Janus Systems\'

Install Janus controls on build server to resolve error.